# Is it possible to make JNI call to Android VNC Server compiled shared lib?

Tags: android, vnc-server

Is it possible to have a Android VNC server compiled lib  inside my android project so that i can make JNI call to start  and stop VNC server instead of rooting device and installing Android VNC server outside of my project.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same for you to call it by JNI or java direct.You absolutely should get the root permission then you can do it.